# How can I modify the contents of an XML file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, file, xml-parsing

Suppose if I have an XML file in a File object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and I want to read and modify the contents in the XML tree and update the File object with the new contents then how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You would have to get the user to upload a file, modify it, then ask the user to download the modified file. You can't directly read or write to the user's disk.

Comment: @caTS I only meant modifying the File object in JavaScript, not on the user's disk. So that the file object can be sent to the backend for processing.